# How can I create a shelltoast?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my application I want to notify the user with the `ShellToast`.

Just by running...

```
var toast = new ShellToast
{
    Title = "Nom nom nom!",
    Content = "More! More! Keep feeding me!",
};
toast.Show();
```

...makes nothing happen, and as I understand it needs to be run from a `ScheduledTaskAgent`. But how do I run this on command, and make sure it only run once?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't use a ShellToast while the app is the foreground app. It's meant to be invoked from a background service while the app isn't the foreground app.

If you want to have a UX similar to that of ShellToast use the [Coding4fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) ToastPrompt control. Here's a code snippet showing how to use it:

```
    private void ToastWrapWithImgAndTitleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var toast = GetToastWithImgAndTitle();
        toast.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

        toast.Show();
    }

    private static ToastPrompt GetToastWithImgAndTitle()
    {
        return new ToastPrompt
        {
            Title = "With Image",
            TextOrientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical,
            Message = LongText,
            ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        };
    }
```

Running this code snippet shows the following:

[image: ToastPrompt control with image]

Comment: Hi. I was trying this code. It gives invalid cross thread access error. How can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

Just a small update: using `ShellToast` when the app is in foreground, is now possible, when using Windows Phone 8 Update 3. Though, they are obscured by other activity such as a phone call or the lock screen. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I think you read it wrong, "toast notifications are displayed when the target app is running in the foreground _but_ is obscured by other activity such as a phone call or the lock screen".