# Windows Phone Toast notification not firing at specified time

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am creating an app with a timer in it.  I want to display a toast notification(or some sort of notification) if the person leaves the app so they know the timer is over.  I used the "PeriodicTask" using ".FromSeconds", but it seemed it didn't fire it at the specified time.

```
   PeriodicTask periodicTask = new PeriodicTask("TaskTest");
     periodicTask.Description = "Task";
     try
     {
         IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["TimerForSchedule"] = TimeNum;
         ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);
         ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest("TaskTest", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(((TimeNum*60)))); 
     }
```

On the "OnInvoke" method for the scheduled agent project, I have the following:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        if (task.Name == "TaskTest")
        {

            int time = Convert.ToInt32(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["TimerForSchedule"]);
            bool periodic = (bool)(task is PeriodicTask);
            ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
            toast.Title = "Done";
            toast.Content = "Timer is over";
            toast.Show();
        }
        NotifyComplete();
        ScheduledActionService.Remove("TaskTest");
    }
```

Everything seems to fire properly because I DO get a notification, but I do not get it at the expected time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what time You get it? Delayed or Faster?

Comment: The first time, it should have been 1 minute and it fired 30 seconds later(so 1.5 minutes), the second time I set it for 30 seconds and it fired in about 10 seconds...so no real pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the time you set to run your PeriodicTask is just a hint for the OS, it does not mean that it will fire it exactly at that time.

Comment: But how to run a task at exact time?

Answer (score 3):

Is your app running in the foreground? If so, the ShellToast won't show up. Your app must be in the background for it to show up. Read more about that and potential workaround at my other @ [How can I create a shelltoast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980864/how-can-i-create-a-shelltoast/13981508#13981508)

Comment: Hi Justin, the app is not running in the foreground.  The toast actually shows up, but not at the expected time.  I tried to fire the toast at one minute and it wasn't consistent when it fired.

Comment: To add to that, ShellToast won't fire when you're on the lock-screen either.