# If my wp app is always in foreground, can I see the ShellToast myself?

Tags: windows-phone-8

My app has a background agent, if it reach a certain condition, it could unscheduled show a ShellToast.

Now my question is that, can I see the ShellToast if my app is always in foreground?

Comment: could it be a clue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980864/how-can-i-create-a-shelltoast

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Taken from the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltoast%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for ShellToast:

> While the ShellToast.Show method can be called from any application, **a
>   toast will not be displayed if the current foreground application is
>   the caller of the ShellToast.Show method**. This means that this should
>   primarily be used by a background agent.